# saving highchart canvas as png image on server

Tags: image, codeigniter, highcharts, server

I'm just wondering has anyone been able to save a canvas image of a highchart onto their server.
I can render the highchart on the canvas fine, but when I save it to the server the image itself is blank but has a file size of 6kb. 
For testing purposes I'm simply hard coding in the dataURL of the canvas image but still can't get the image to show(I'm simply ruling out the fact that its not a case of me not transferring the data correctly when generating the image).
Ive also tried taking a regular dataURL of a cloud and that image appears fine.

```
$img = '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';

 $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = 'download/image3.png';
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
        print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Anyone know what might be wrong? I need to save these as images on the server because I need to show them in a pdf afterwards but can't seem to find another solution.I'm using code igniter also.

Comment: var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); does not work and saves it as blank?

Comment: @mansim yes the file is generating and has a file size of 6kb but image is blank when I open it unfortunately

Comment: and it should work like here? the saving as png image? http://www.highcharts.com/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost

Comment: @mansim what I'm actually doing is calling this function in my controller which automatically saves the image to my server, so I don't actually click the menu on the highchart itself, I just grab the svg, put it onto a canvas and get the dataURL which is the $img variable above. (I'm just hard coding it for testing purposes)